# Error al enviar texto en una notificación

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

Tengo una app en la que envías una notificación con el título y cuerpo que quieras a otros dispositivos desde `firebase`, utilizo funcyions, el caso es que a la hora de escribir el texto que quiero en la notificación la notificación funciona, pero solo pone el de index.js y es estático, y no quiero eso, quiero que el usuario cree sus notificaciones con el contenido que desee . dejo el código Gracias.

Actividad principal

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

import app.bsmo.ismael034.com.bsmo.R;

public class MainActivity7 extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef;

    String dataTitle, dataMessage;
    EditText title, message;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.noti);

        // Handle possible data accompanying notification message.
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                if (key.equals("title")) {
                    dataTitle = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
                }
                if (key.equals("message")) {
                    dataMessage = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
                }
            }

            showAlertDialog();

        }

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = database.getReference("messages");

        title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);

    }

    private void showAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Message");
        builder.setMessage("title: " + dataTitle + "\n" + "message: " + dataMessage);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        builder.show();
    }

    public void subscribeToTopic(View view) {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("notifications");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Subscribed to Topic: Notifications", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        myRef.push().setValue(new Message(title.getText().toString(), message.getText().toString()));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

FCM Service

```
        import android.app.NotificationManager;
        import android.app.PendingIntent;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.media.RingtoneManager;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
        import android.util.Log;

        import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
        import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import app.bsmo.ismael034.com.bsmo.R;

public class FCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        /* There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed. */
        String notificationTitle = null, notificationBody = null;
        String dataTitle = null, dataMessage = null;

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
            dataTitle = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            dataMessage = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            notificationTitle = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            notificationBody = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
        sendNotification(notificationTitle, notificationBody, dataTitle, dataMessage);
    }

    /**
     //     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     //     */
    private void sendNotification(String notificationTitle, String notificationBody, String dataTitle, String dataMessage) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity7.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", dataTitle);
        intent.putExtra("message", dataMessage);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Message.java

```
public class Message {
    private String title, message;

    public Message(){}

    public Message(String title, String message) {
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

index.js

```
// imports firebase-functions module
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
// imports firebase-admin module
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
/* Listens for new messages added to /messages/:pushId and sends a notification to subscribed users */
exports.pushNotification = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}').onWrite( event => {
console.log('Push notification event triggered');
/* Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database */
    var valueObject = event.data.val();
/* Create a notification and data payload. They contain the notification information, and message to be sent respectively */ 
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'App Name',
            body: "Notification",
            sound: "Noti BSMO"
        },
        data: {
            title: valueObject.title,
            message: valueObject.message
        }
    };
/* Create an options object that contains the time to live for the notification and the priority. */
    const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24 //24 hours
    };
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("notifications", payload, options);
});
```

Comment: esta parte debes modificar: 0 /* ID of notification */, debes asignarle un id dinamico, para que las notificaciones se diferencien

Comment: Donde consigo ese id dinámico, me lo da firebase??

Comment: Con eso me podría poner el texto que quiera a la notificación?

Comment: El id lo puedes sacar por ejemplo de la hora, ponerle como id la fecha en la que estás pasada a segundos, así no se te va a repetir seguro

Comment: @Ismael si solucionaste este problema agrega una respuesta basada en [answer], de otra forma puedes eliminar la pregunta ya que no es muy clara.

Comment: Esl problema no esta solucionado, el problema es que quiero mandar un texto elegido por mi en una notificacion y no me funciona porque dolo me sale el texto estático proporcionado por elindex.js